MUI Autocomplete groupBy twice
In MUI autocomplete is there any way to group by category AND subcategory? currently in the docs I've only found the option to group by a single 'parent'
So for example I want the options to be:
Fruits
--Citrus
----Lemon
--Berries
----Strawberry
...
